# Google ADT loading Android L on every save - What is going on?

Tags: android, operation

I'm working on an Android project get following operation on every file save.
This problem occurs especially when opening XML files and saving them. This for all kind of XML: layouts, data sources, manifest, ...

*What is going on? This time-losing operation makes me crazy.*

```
"Loading data for android L (preview)
Android L (Preview) Widgets and layouts"
```

How to stop this?

Update: This also happens for Android 2.3.3 and is somehow related to versions. Any suggestions?

[image: Waiting for operation]

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you're targeting the L API (20)?

What's your `minSdkVerion` and `targetSdkVersion`?

Comment: Do you have any other projects open that may be targeting API 20? Try taking a look at `build.grade`, and also `Sync Project with Gradle Files`, and see if that resolves anything.

Answer (score 0):

Android L API loads because of the Targeting version

check your **MinSdkVersion** and **TragetSDKVersion ?**

if you change this your L loading might be stopped
and better close all your other projects in emulator because in runtime it can load the app data's which was already executed in Android L

clean your project fully and run the app in which API level you want . I hope you will not see again loading Android L after you do this

Comment: This problem occurs especially when opening XML files and saving them. This for all kind of XML: layouts, data sources, manifest, ...